# How to run sqlcl outside of SQL Developer directory

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

I have installed the Oracle client [`WINDOWS.X64_213000_client.zip`](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle21c-windows-downloads.html)
and I want to use the bundled `sql.exe` to run SQL scripts in my project directory.

The `sql.exe` is located in the following directory which I have added to my Path env var:

```
E:\Oracle_21c\app\client\product\21.0.0\client_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin
```

The jar files are in

```
E:\Oracle_21c\app\client\product\21.0.0\client_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\lib
```

The following works:

```
cd E:\Oracle_21c\app\client\product\21.0.0\client_1\sqldeveloper

\sqldeveloper\bin\sql -LOGON user/password@tns_db_alias  
   select 'a' as a from dual;
```

But I can only run it from that directory, if I try to run `sql.exe` from the path directory by not qualifying it as `bin\sql` then an exception is thrown.

> >sql -LOGON user/password@tns_db_alias
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hc/core5/http/ParseException

What can I do to make `sql.exe` runnable and accessible via the path?
So that I can be in any arbitrary directory e.g. `\projects\myproj\`
and run scripts using `sql.exe`

```
cd \projects\myproj\
sql -LOGON user/password@tns_db_alias my_db_script.sql
```

Comment: If you run sql /nolog does it also error? If not, what does show tns bring back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug.

When I try to run the included 'sql' (SQLcl) program at all from this distribution -

```
c:\oracle\client\product\21.0.0\client_1\bin>sql /nolog
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hc/core5/http/ParseException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.newscriptrunner.CommandRegistry.addListener(CommandRegistry.java:75)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.newscriptrunner.CommandRegistry.addForAllStmtsListener(CommandRegistry.java:649)
        at oracle.dbtools.commands.NetCommands.registerCommands(NetCommands.java:28)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.scriptrunner.cmdline.SqlCli.initSqlcl(SqlCli.java:196)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.scriptrunner.cmdline.SqlCli.runSqlcl(SqlCli.java:962)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.scriptrunner.cmdline.SqlCli.main(SqlCli.java:369)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hc.core5.http.ParseException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 10 more
```

Go to [oracle.com/sqlcl](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html) - download the standalone Zip. Put it in it's own directory, it will run just fine.

We'll have the 21c distribution updated ASAP to fix this for client downloads.

Workaround, update your path to include ..product\21.0.0\client_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin

If you run the sql.exe out of this directory, it works -

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeff, the standalone version works, but only for a thin client url.
if I use a TNSALIAS then I get an error  

"
Incompatible version of libocijdbc[Jdbc:211000, Jdbc-OCI:213000
".  
Also I don't want to run from the bin directory, because my scripts are in the project directory, and also include other scripts with relative paths.

Comment: Weird a 21.1 and 21.3 driver combo should be compatible